# Loading many fragments based on a JSON source using Fragment State Adapter

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have a Fragment State Pager Adapter and a list of Questions which I retrieve from a server as JSON. Does anyone know how I can dynamically (based on the number of questions returned from the server), create many instances of the same fragment, and load them into my activity's view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about first saving the questions in a list and then accordingly generating your fragments on the Adapter

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know how to generate the fragments from a list. Any tutorials or references, you can show me?

Comment: See some example related to pager adapter